# How do I know which one is a stable version of Cyanogenmode on this list?'

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, custom-roms

I am trying to install a new ROM on my phone, but I have no clue which one is the stable release:

[image]

Is it the latest release?

What's the difference between the release and release recovery?

Cheers

Comment: Release contains zip file(ROM) that you can install using TWRP. Release recovery may be cyanogen recovery image file.

Comment: One thing to know: CyanogenMod is now dead, rebadged into LineageOS. Since LOS doesn't have an official build server as of yet, you should find builds in appropriate forums, or build one yourself (not so easy).

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two different products available here: Cyanogenmod (release), and Cyanogenmod Recovery (release recovery).

While Release is the custom ROM in itself, Release Recovery is a special recovery partition used to load Cyanogenmod onto the device if you don't already have it or TWRP installed. It is also used to do other low level system stuff if booting into the live system isn't possible or appropriate.